# Looking for a Cumulative Total for Unique Customers Only Month by Month

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, window-functions

I am trying to create a cumulative count for unique customers only by the month they purchased. The example Table is:

| customer_email | cohortMonth |
| --- | --- |
| abc@gmail.com | 10/2019 |
| def@gmail.com | 10/2019 |
| ghi@gmail.com | 10/2019 |
| def@gmail.com | 11/2019 |
| jkl@gmail.com | 11/2019 |
| def@gmail.com | 12/2019 |

The output I am looking for is the total Customers for 10/2019 would be 3, The cumulative total customers for 11/2019 would be 4 taking all of the customers purchased in 10/2019 and adding jkl@gmail.com as this is the only Unique customer email for the month. The cumulative total customers for 12/2019 will still be 4 as no new customers purchased in this month.

| cohortMonth | cumulative_total_customers |
| --- | --- |
| 10/2019 | 3 |
| 11/2019 | 4 |
| 12/2019 | 4 |

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
with dataset as (
    SELECT 
        customer,
        date_trunc('month', date(purchase_date)) purchase_date 
    FROM (
            VALUES 
                ('abc@gmail.com', '2019-10-05'),
                ('def@gmail.com', '2019-10-10'),
                ('ghi@gmail.com', '2019-10-15'),
                ('def@gmail.com', '2019-11-03'),
                ('jkl@gmail.com', '2019-11-28'),
                ('def@gmail.com', '2019-12-12')
        ) AS x (customer, purchase_date)
)


SELECT purchase_date,
       COUNT( customer ) AS daily_cumulative_count
FROM ( 
    SELECT 
        a.purchase_date AS purchase_date,
        b.customer
    FROM dataset AS a
    INNER JOIN dataset AS b ON a.purchase_date >= b.purchase_date
    GROUP BY 
        a.purchase_date,
        b.customer
     ) 
GROUP BY 
    purchase_date
;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The ideal solution would be to use a `window` function with a `DISTINCT` clause so that to eliminate the duplicated emails :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (cohortMonth)
       cohortMonth
     , count(DISTINCT customer_email) OVER (ORDER BY cohortMonth RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS cumulative_total_customers
  FROM mytable
```

But I get a Postgres error :

> DISTINCT is not implemented for window functions

So in order to eliminate the duplicates, we have two solutions :

**Solution 1** : build the array of customer_email by cohortMonth and then eliminate the duplicates with a query

```
SELECT l.cohortMonth, array_length(array_agg(DISTINCT a), 1) AS cumulative_total_customers
FROM
   ( SELECT DISTINCT ON (cohortMonth)
            cohortMonth
          , array_agg(customer_email) OVER (ORDER BY cohortMonth RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS email_array
       FROM mytable
   ) AS l
CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(l.email_array) AS a
GROUP BY l.cohortMonth
```

**Solution 2** : build the array of customer_email by cohortMonth and then eliminate the duplicates with a specific function `count_distinct_array_element`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION count_distinct_array_element(x anyarray) RETURNS bigint LANGUAGE sql AS $$
SELECT count(DISTINCT e) FROM unnest(x) AS e ; $$ ;

SELECT DISTINCT ON (cohortMonth)
       cohortMonth
     , count_distinct_array_element(array_agg(customer_email) OVER (ORDER BY cohortMonth RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)) AS cumulative_total_customers
  FROM mytable
```

**Result :**

| cohortmonth | cumulative_total_customers |
| --- | --- |
| 10/2019 | 3 |
| 11/2019 | 4 |
| 12/2019 | 4 |

See test results in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/I0jD0KxV)

Comment: I get the error: com.amazon.redshift.util.RedshiftException: ERROR: SELECT DISTINCT ON is not supported

Answer (score 0):

We can do this simply we two levels of aggregation.

```
select cohort_month, 
    sum(count(*)) over(order by cohort_month) cumulative_total_customers 
from (select min(cohort_month) cohort_month from mytable group by customer_email) t
group by cohort_month
order by cohort_month
```

The subquery retrieves the earliest appearance of each customer, which we can then aggregate by month to generate the cumulative count.

If there are months without new customer, and you still want them to show in the resultset, then we can tweak the query a litle:

```
select c.cohort_month, 
    sum(count(t.cohort_month)) over(order by c.cohort_month) cumulative_total_customers 
from (select distinct cohort_month from mytable) c
left join (select min(cohort_month) cohort_month from mytable group by customer_email) t using (cohort_month)
group by c.cohort_month
order by c.cohort_month
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/BEPyZmdI)**

Comment: Hi, thank you. I get the error: com.amazon.redshift.util.RedshiftException: ERROR: Aggregate window functions with an ORDER BY clause require a frame clause
I am using a "With" clause to build the initial table to get the customer email and the cohortMonth column:
with 
user_cohorts as (
    SELECT   customer_email
            ,MIN(DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', timestamp)) as cohortMonth
    FROM public.fact_shopify_orders
    GROUP BY 1
    having cohortMonth between '2019-10-01' and '2020-09-30'

Comment: @MrLockett: are you running Redshift? You tagged the question Postgres. Both are different database products, although somehow similar...

Comment: Hi, I am running this in Mode Analytics which uses Redshift database but I thought used Postgresql as its language.